# How to redirect to page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, flash, redirect, process, background

i am using one swf file.on click i have some background process.after finish the process i want to redirect to particular page.but its not working.what should i do to redirect to page.i am using asp.net
?
reply me soon

Thanking You
Samir

Comment: swf to aspx page
or
aspx to aspx page ??

Answer (score 1):

Hai samir,

Try adding this `<object  onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')/>"` or `<a href="http://www.google.com"><embed scr="test.swf"></embed></a>`

For ref see this http://forums.asp.net/t/1322013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

background process ?

in library 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect

in other thread use event sync

you must keep response is  open

Comment: if you wait swf event (like end or click)  ,swf->javascript-> xmlRequest  .
and  redirect in swf event , swf->javascipt : location.href='target url' –